# Trouble using method get in php

Tags: php, forms, get

Hello my web page is hanging after executing this small part of the code.
It seems that is related to the use of the `_GET` table

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['radGr']))
  {
     $radGroup=$_GET['radGr']);
  }
?>

<form action='Exec3.php' method='get'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Operator</legend>
  <label>+
    <input type='radio' name='radGr' 
    <?php if($radGr == 0){ echo 'Checked=checked' ;} ?>
    value=0 >
  </label>
  <label>-
    <input type='radio' name='radGr' 
    <?php if($radGr == 1){ echo 'Checked=checked' ;} ?>
    value=1 >
  </label>  
</fieldset>
<input type='submit' value='transfert'>
</form>
```

Do you see something wrong in my code ?

Thanks.

Comment: `$radGr != $radGroup` (and don't forget to set it to a default value if it's not set since you use it anyway). oh, and extra parenthesis on line four

Comment: GET is not a method. _GET is not a table. $_GET is an array.

Comment: $radGroup=$_GET['radGr']); Extra bracket at end...It seems that your script is throwing error. Try to enable errors in php.ini if you don't have them enabled.

Comment: Looks like the page is not hang. It just crashed on usage of `radGr`, which is not defined, but silently suppressed the error. You might want to examine your php.ini settings to enable exceptions/errors be propagated to the browser (in your development environment. Don't do it in production)

Comment: another point: your form sending data to another page which is `Exec3.php` is that page is same page?

Comment: if (array_key_exists('radGr', $_REQUEST)) $radGroup = $_REQUEST['radGr']; is better execution than your first codeblock. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: It was indeed the extra bracket at the end of line 4.I Removed it and it worked like a charm !! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `)` near `$radGroup=$_GET['radGr']);`

just remove it.

and you can change your code to :

```
<input type='radio' name='radGr' 
<?php echo(!empty($radGroup) && $radGroup == 0)? 'Checked=checked' : ''; ?>  
value=0 >
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$radGr` does not exist, it should be `$radGroup`.

Change it in your php within the form.